# How to display a drop-down list of RDS instance snapshot ID's when creating a new stack from a template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I wrote a CloudFormation template which creates a Postgres instance and restores data from a previously backed up DB instance snapshot.

I want to enable the user which is going to work with this template the option of selecting the rds instance snapshots from a drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDS instance snapshots are not in the list of [AWS Specific Parameter Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types), so there's no way to have an automatic dropdown.

You can however list the possible values in the template as `AllowedValues`, but this will obviously not update automatically.

Comment: Yes agree with you but I'm able to perform the same scenario in different manner.

So I'm deploying my CloudFormation template using GitHub actions and GitHub actions provide this facility.

Thanks.